# How can i install kubeseal on windows?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

how can I please install kubeseal on windows with Linux WSL?

- I found that I need chocolaty to do that but that wasn't clear for me

Answer (score 1):

### Windows WSL - Ubuntu

For Ubuntu on Windows try this, it worked for me:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets/releases/download/v0.16.0/kubeseal-linux-amd64 -O /usr/local/bin/kubeseal

sudo chmod 755 /usr/local/bin/kubeseal
```

### Windows PowerShell

A simple PowerShell script that downloads the latest kubeseal CLI for Windows and adds it to the user's PATH:
https://github.com/jordan-owen/kubeseal-windows-installer

Open PowerShell as Admin user and run the script code.